# How to remove my account from the Chocolatey Gallery?

Tags: account-management

I would like to remove my account from [Chocolatey Gallery](https://chocolatey.org):

- My chocolatey packages are not updated anymore as [ketarin](https://github.com/030/chocolateyautomatic) does not run as my Windows laptop is broken
- Since November 2015 I am not using Windows anymore and I have decided to continue using linux
- I receive multiple messages [whether packages could be updated on Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/profiles/utrecht)
- I would like to transfer ownership so other maintainers could update the packages

**Alternative**

I could continue, but then I would like to use an open source windows system in the cloud for free so the packages could be updated automatically

I have searched the web, I have logged in to chocolatey gallary but did not find a button to remove my account.

Comment: They have a Contact Us form on the site.  This may be something they have to handle directly.

Comment: @jonsca I have sent them a message

Comment: Are you familiar with this repository? https://github.com/chocolatey/chocolatey-coreteampackages If you want, you could move your packages to this repo, and then the Windows Server that we have running Windows would continue to monitor them for changes.  That way, you could continue to maintain the packages, but we would do the work of running the ketarin instance.  Thoughts?

Comment: @GaryEwanPark I will check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically you use the contact us form or use contact site admins from a package page to remove your account.